# Is there anyway I can see when I became friends with someone on Facebook?

Tags: api, facebook

I want to create a visualization where I see friends being added as time passes but I don't think the Facebook API tells me since how long I am friends with someone.

Comment: Why wonder if the Facebook API will tell you that?  Either it does or it doesn't, and you can presumably check.

Comment: I wonder because:
1) It might be some hidden/undocumented API feature or some known API feature that I am unaware of
2) OR there might be a page on Facebook that I can parse manually from my own profile - Facebook has tons of utility pages that are hard to find from just the homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to [Real-time Updates](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/realtime) for friends, so facebook should notify your app when new friend is added (in theory, haven't tried it myself :) ).

Answer (score 0):

You can get your most recent connections using

```
me?fields=posts.fields(status_type)
```

You can also manually look at the relationship you have with certain users at https://www.facebook.com/username1?and=username2